# pam ldap password reset on terminal

Tags: centos, ldap, solaris, pam, reset-password

I have a Solaris machine running that is connected to an LDAP. Users can login using their credentials stored in LDAP. When a user forgets his/her password, I can reset the password in LDAP and force the user to pick a new password after successful login (terminal and GUI).

Trying this on CentOS using PAM does not work (login screen just rejects the password as if it was wrong) or I am not quite sure how to configure PAM.

`/etc/pam.d/password-auth-ac` looks like this:

```
#%PAM-1.0
# This file is auto-generated.
# User changes will be destroyed the next time authconfig is run.
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so try_first_pass
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 1000 quiet_success
auth        sufficient    pam_ldap.so use_first_pass
auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     required      pam_unix.so broken_shadow
account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 1000 quiet
account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_ldap.so
account     required      pam_permit.so

password    requisite     pam_pwquality.so try_first_pass local_users_only retry=3 authtok_type=
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so sha512 shadow try_first_pass use_authtok
password    sufficient    pam_ldap.so use_authtok
password    required      pam_deny.so

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
-session     optional      pam_systemd.so
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
session     optional      pam_ldap.so
```

`/etc/nsswitch.conf` looks like this:

```
passwd:     files sss ldap
shadow:     files sss ldap
group:      files sss ldap
netgroup:   files sss ldap
...
```

I already looked into the configuration on the Solaris machine but that thing is ancient...

So again, what I need is that when a user successfully logs on with his/her password, the terminal will ask the user to immediately change the password.
Any help is greatly appreciated.